PSU Won’t Start with Fans Connected on Gigabyte MC12-LE0 Motherboard with Seasonic SS-400H2U PSU
I’m in the process of building my homelab server but have run into a snag while trying to boot the integrated IPMI using my Seasonic SS-400H2U Active PFC PSU. The fans spin briefly, but the IPMI status LED doesn’t light up.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Removed all RAM sticks one by one.
Swapped the 4+4 CPU connector for an 8-pin connector.
Disconnected all the fans, including the CPU fan, from the motherboard.
After disconnecting everything, the IPMI successfully booted, allowing me to access the system and perform a BIOS update. But when I reconnected just the CPU fan, the system refused to start.
I tested an old FSP HD700 ATX PSU, and the IPMI booted without any issues. I checked the output voltages on the Seasonic PSU's 24-pin, 8-pin, and 4+4 connectors—everything was normal.
For further troubleshooting, I hooked up the Seasonic PSU to my older B450 Aorus Pro motherboard with a CPU and single fan. The CPU heated up, and the fan spun, though the motherboard displayed a CPU error.
Finally, I booted the MC12-LE0 motherboard (with RAM and NVMe installed) using the Seasonic PSU, leaving the fans disconnected. The IPMI booted successfully, and after reconnecting the fans, everything worked. I could control the fans via IPMI and boot into the BIOS.
Now I’m at a loss. It’s frustrating to have to disconnect and reconnect the fans with each restart. If anyone has any suggestions or has faced something similar, I’d really appreciate your advice!
Thanks in advance!
Homelab:

Gigabyte MC12-LE0 (with last BIOS version: "F16")
AMD Ryzen 7 Pro 4750G
4x M391A2K43BB1-CPBQ
1x PWM CPU
Fan 4x 3Pin Fans
1x 1TB NVMe

